# Java Lambda: Iterate over 2 dim-array keeping the current index

Tags: java, java-8

I'm new to Java 8's Lambda Expressions and I want to formulate the following:
I have a 2-dimensional array which I want to iterate over several times in my application code and do stuff with the items in the array. Before i'd do the following:

```
    public static abstract class BlaBlaIterator {

            private final BlaBla[][] blabla;

            public BlaBlaIterator(final BlaBla[][] blabla) {
                this.blabla = blabla;
            }

            public void iterate() {
                final int size = blabla.length;
                for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
                        final BlaBla bla = blabla[x][y];
                        iterateAction(x, y, bla, bla == null);
                    }
                }
            }

            public abstract void iterateAction(int x, int y, BlaBla bla, boolean isNull);
        }
```

and then

```
    BlaBla[][] blabla = ...

    new BlaBlaIterator(blabla) {

        @Override
        public void iterateAction(final int x, final int y, final BlaBla bla, final boolean isNull) {
            //...
        }
    }.iterate();
```

Crucial thing: I need access to the current x/y and I need to get calculated things like the isNull.

What I want to do now is to convert this to lambda. I want to write something like this:

```
    BlaBla[] blabla = ...
    blabla.stream().forEach((x, y, blabla, isNull) -> ... );
```

To get a stream from the 2-dimensional Array I can do

```
    Arrays.stream(field).flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x))
```

But then I loose the x/y info and cannot pass calculated stuff like isNull. How can i do this?

Comment: Even if s.o. comes up with an answer: A two-dimensional array in its classic form just isn't a stream. Note that you are asking for x and y to be part of the final processing call - the sequence of `blabla[0][0]` to the last element just can't be separated from the index pair.

Comment: IMHO it is more readable and easy to maintain. When you hold a hammer in your hand everything looks like a nail :)

Just because we have streams does not mean we should use them at all places :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be honest I would keep the traditionnal nested loop, IMO this is a much cleaner approach. Streams are not a substition for all the "old" Java code. Nevertheless, I posted some possible approaches.

### First approach

Here's a first possible approach (Object-oriented). Create a class `ArrayElement` to hold the indices:

```
class ArrayElement<V> {
    public final int row;
    public final int col;
    public final V elem;
    ...
}
```

Then you'll need to create a method that creates a Stream of elements from a single array (the one that we will call for `flatMap`), and `iterateAction` just print out the current instance

```
private static <T> Stream<ArrayElement<T>> createStream(int row, T[] arr) {
    OfInt columns = IntStream.range(0, arr.length).iterator();
    return Arrays.stream(arr).map(elem -> new ArrayElement<>(row, columns.nextInt(), elem));
} 

private static <V> void iterateAction(ArrayElement<V> elem) {
    System.out.println(elem);
}
```

Finally the main looks like this:

```
String[][] arr = {{"One", "Two"}, {"Three", "Four"}};
OfInt rows = IntStream.range(0, arr.length).iterator();
Arrays.stream(arr)
      .flatMap(subArr -> createStream(rows.nextInt(), subArr))
      .forEach(Main::iterateAction);
```

and outputs:

```
ArrayElement [row=0, col=0, elem=One]
ArrayElement [row=0, col=1, elem=Two]
ArrayElement [row=1, col=0, elem=Three]
ArrayElement [row=1, col=1, elem=Four]
```

This solution has the disadvantage that it creates a new Object for each Object in the array.

### Second approach

The second approach is more direct, it's the same idea but you don't create a new ArrayElement instance for each elem in the array. Again this could be done in a one liner but the lamdba would become ugly so I splitted those up in methods (like in the first approach):

```
public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] arr = { {"One", "Two"}, {null, "Four"}};
        OfInt rows = IntStream.range(0, arr.length).iterator();
        Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(subArr -> iterate(subArr, rows.nextInt()));
    }
    static <T> void iterate(T[] arr, int row) {
        OfInt columns = IntStream.range(0, arr.length).iterator();
        Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(elem -> iterateAction(row, columns.nextInt(), elem, elem == null));
    }
    static <T> void iterateAction(int x, int y, T elem, boolean isNull) {
        System.out.println(x+", "+y+", "+elem+", "+isNull);
    }    
}
```

and it outputs:

```
0, 0, One, false
0, 1, Two, false
1, 0, null, true
1, 1, Four, false
```

### Third approach

Using two instances of `AtomicInteger`

```
String[][] arr = {{"One", "Two"}, {null, "Four"}};
AtomicInteger rows = new AtomicInteger();
Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(subArr -> {
    int row = rows.getAndIncrement();
    AtomicInteger colums = new AtomicInteger();
    Arrays.stream(subArr).forEach(e -> iterateAction(row, colums.getAndIncrement(), e, e == null));
});
```

which produces the same output as above.

### My conclusion

It's duable using Streams but I really prefer the nested loop in your use-case since you need both the x and y values.

Comment: I definitely agree with the suggestion to just keep the existing nested for loops. Streams are great for many use cases, but are not appropriate for everything. While you can force your use case into streams, it does not make the code any easier to read or maintain and almost certainly performs worse.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!! I will use them to get more familiar with lambas. But the solutions don't look as elegant as i expected them to be, my "old approach" is much easier to read as u said already. So I will stay with the nested loops eventually.

Comment: @user2849355 Yes clearly if you need the indices the nested loop is the best option. Of course if you would only need to proceed the elements `Arrays.stream(arr).flatMap(Arrays::stream).forEach(System.out::println);` is a cool one-liner approach. But yes, while the new stuff in Java 8 is very cool, we don't have to forget the fundamentals :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue, similar to the different forms of `for`-loop. If you are not interested in the indices, you can imply say:

```
for(BlaBla[] array: blabla) for(BlaBla element: array) action(element);
```

But if you are interested in the indices, you can’t use the for-each loop but have to iterate over the indices and get the array element in the loop body. Similarly, you have to stream the indices when using `Stream` and need the indices:

```
IntStream.range(0, blabla.length)
         .forEach(x -> IntStream.range(0, blabla[x].length)
             .forEach(y -> {
                       final BlaBla bla = blabla[x][y];
                       iterateAction(x, y, bla, bla == null);
             })
         );
```

This is a 1:1 translation which has the advantage of not requiring additional classes, but it consists of two distinct `Stream` operations rather than one fused operation, as would be preferred.

A single, fused operation might look like this:

helped class:

```
class ArrayElement {
    final int x, y;
    BlaBla element;
    final boolean isNull;
    ArrayElement(int x, int y, BlaBla obj) {
        this.x=x; this.y=y;
        element=obj; isNull=obj==null;
    }
}
```

actual operation:

```
IntStream.range(0, blabla.length).boxed()
         .flatMap(x -> IntStream.range(0, blabla[x].length)
                                .mapToObj(y->new ArrayElement(x, y, blabla[x][y])))
         .forEach(e -> iterateAction(e.x, e.y, e.element, e.isNull));
```