# Java : is it possible to have 'nested' map methods (java.util.stream)?

Tags: java, java-8

Given an array of ints (e.g. `[8, 7, 5, 3]`), I want to verify that the numbers are pairwise co-primes.

I wonder whether it is possible to do it with two nested `Arrays.stream` and `map` methods, something like : `Arrays.stream(r -> gcd(r, Map...)`.

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you want to do? Do you wish to execute a method on each pair of integers from the input array? What would the output be?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem reduces to how to generate all the pairs in the array. Then you can just use `allMatch` to check for the pairwise co-prime property.

This would be a possible implementation:

```
private static boolean isCoPrime(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) return a == 1;
    return isCoPrime(b, a % b);
}

private static boolean isPairwiseCoPrime(int[] arr) {
    return IntStream.of(arr)
                    .allMatch(a -> IntStream.of(arr).filter(b -> b != a).allMatch(b -> isCoPrime(a, b)));
}
```

This will generate all possible pairs and checks if they are co-prime or not. However this makes unnecessary computations as you are checking, for example, if the pair (8, 7) is co-prime and  then the pair (7, 8). So another workaround would be this:

```
private static boolean isPairwiseCoPrime(int[] arr) {
    return IntStream.range(0, arr.length - 1)
                    .allMatch(i -> IntStream.range(i + 1, arr.length).allMatch(j -> isCoPrime(arr[i], arr[j])));
}
```

which is basically the pre-Java 8 translation of:

```
private static boolean isPairwiseCoPrime(int[] arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
             if(!isCoPrime(arr[i], arr[j])) {
                 return false;
             }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Just as a note, as I explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27756617/java-lambda-iterate-over-2-dim-array-keeping-the-current-index/27757136#27757136), the Stream approach is not a substitution for everything, sometimes it's cleaner and shorter to use the traditional loop approach.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! (PS: It seems that your 'isCoPrime' doesn't always return a boolean).

Comment: @user3166747 Ah sorry for that! I forgot to update the code. `isCoPrime` is called recursively. Updated :-)